# Determining if a contactless VISA transaction was MSD vs EMV/qVSDC

Tags: contactless-smartcard, emv

I'm configuring a terminal for use with contactless VISA cards. I understand that terminals can be setup to support legacy MSD mode, EMV/qVSDC mode or both.

I have an EMV testing tool, so I am able to see all the communication between the testing card and the terminal. Generally, I've found AIP Byte 2 bit 8 gives an indication if the card supports EMV contactless mode, but this doesn't seem to be the case for VISA cards.

Assuming a terminal is configured for both, how would someone recognise if a transaction occurred using MSD mode or qVSDC mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSD mode is implemented for infrastructures which are not yet upgraded to process full grade emv transactions, but at the same time wants to use the capability of the chip to increase the security. In case of MSD transaction, the there will not be DE55 elements, but a dynamic cvv(CVN 17) in track. Otherwise, it will look like a magnetic stripe transaction.

Where as qvsdc is a full grade EMV transactions, it has cryptogram and other DE55 elemsts.

In fact I heard Visa is looking to establish a sunset date for the contactless MSD processing.

Comment: I'm getting from this that in MSD mode there will be no cryptogram present? Is the same true for other card brands using mag-stripe mode, such as AMEX and MasterCard?

Comment: May I ask you which among the below type of MSD are you using. 
1. 'MSD Legacy' which provides Dynamic Card Verification Value (dCVV) (no cryptogram ) or, 
2. 'MSD CVN17' which offer an application cryptogram. For detailed information you will have to refer Visa Contactless Payment Specification Version 2.1  
I am not sure about MasterCard or Amex.

Comment: @libemv.so1.0.1 We are not supporting MSD CVN17. TBH, I'm don't believe we're supporting MSD Legacy either. I'm just trying to understand from a high level the best way to determine if a contactless card was processed via MSD or EMV based on the data returned.

Comment: if it was me looking as a payment processor or issuer I would be simply looking at pos entry code (DE22.1) which will be 91 for MSD and 07 for contatctless vsdc chip.

Comment: libemv.so.1.0.1 Yeah, I believe that's the field I'm trying to find the value for. I'm working on the card reader side of the solution that will send data up to the server, and through to the acquirer. Trying to find a way to differentiate at the time the card is read, so we can build the transaction data appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Per the visa contactless implementation guide dcvv is sent with msd and NO chip data. CVN17 is for when msd data AND chip data. and CVN18 is for full emv contactless.